# How to load table view cell order by some fields from soap?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I displayed sales details of gas station from soap on labels.I used labels for display but it is not useful for users.

Here my app is empty.I input dates and station name from textfields.
[image]

Here entered dates and station name for display sales details of between two date.
[image]

Every station has a region and I have region name in web service.I have 7 regions.(e.g) Region2 has 90 stations,region3 has 45 statiions.I want display station details by Region Name(Now by station name )

When I enter dates,Region name  click ok

table view cell will be like;

```
Station Name1 -Station Code
K95       
123 units  4000Liters   9889000 USD
Diesel
21 units   3200 liters   3232320 USD    
LPG 
98 units   3421 liters   3232322 USD

Station Name2 -Station Code    
K95       
123 units  4000Liters   9889000 USD
Diesel
21 units   3200 liters   3232320 USD
LPG 
98 units   3421 liters   3232322 USD

Station Name3 -Station Code
K95       
123 units  4000Liters   9889000 USD
Diesel
21 units   3200 liters   3232320 USD
LPG 
98 units   3421 liters   3232322 USD

.    
.
.

Station Name99 -Station Code    
K95       
123 units  4000Liters   9889000 USD
Diesel
21 units   3200 liters   3232320 USD
LPG 
98 units   3421 liters   3232322 USD
```

How can I use and load table cell for display my station sales details order by region name.Is it possible? Share your tips :)

Comment: Well you have a datasource for your table which is probably an array of dictionaries or custom objects, well you can sort the array by region or by any other  attributes ;)

Comment: I know I can sort but how :) I need a sample like this :)

Answer (score 1):

Example scenario: your dataSource is an NSArray and the order is by the atributte `region` of your objects:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"region" ascending:YES];     
[yourArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
```

For more info, at Apple docs:

- [Apple Collections Programming](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Arrays.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000132-SW5)
- [NSSortDescriptor Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: I think you dont understand my question.I did not asked sorting.I asked load table cell from my web service like display on labels.And sort by Region.When I select Region1 I want to see all Region1's station details like labels.